# Update Text in Custom View via Thread : Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I want give pop-up & go-back effect to text in Custome View. I am trying to update Text Size In a Cutome View via Thread, which update Text Size and `PostInvalidate();`. But it dont show any effect in Custome View.

Custome View OnDraw Method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawText(carMessage, getPercentOfWidth(40),getPercentOfHeight(20),fontPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(carSpriteImage, carspritePosition.x , carspritePosition.y, null);
}
```

Font Updater Thread Class Code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();    

    while(true){

        paint.setTextSize(minSize);
        Log.i("Font Thread!", "Min Font Size="+minSize);
        customeView.setCarMessage("Click Me");
        customeView.setFontPaint(paint);
        customeView.postInvalidate();

        try {
             Thread.sleep(700);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        paint.setTextSize(maxSize);
        customeView.setCarMessage("To Stop");
        customeView.setFontPaint(paint);
        Log.i("Font Thread!", "Max Font Size="+maxSize);
        customeView.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/

Comment: No buddy i am asking to update customeView not activity.

Comment: Have You tried to put logs in onDarw() to show values of carMessage, for example? How many calls have You observed and which values?

Answer (score 0):

I made this in my project https://github.com/donvigo/CustomProgressControls.
Look at method `changePercentage` in `CircleRoadProgress` class.